# TypeError: ('Keyword argument not understood:', 'subsample')

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am training a Keras model using and it's throwing an error.

I replaced Convolution2D with Conv2D that doesn't work.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-99-e85c5751f266> in <module>()
     26   model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=optimizer)
     27   return model
---> 28 model = nvidia_model()
     29 print(model.summary())

5 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/generic_utils.py in validate_kwargs(kwargs, allowed_kwargs, error_message)
    776   for kwarg in kwargs:
    777     if kwarg not in allowed_kwargs:
--> 778       raise TypeError(error_message, kwarg)
    779 
    780 

TypeError: ('Keyword argument not understood:', 'subsample')
```

modified code

i am using keras 2.2.4 currently
i am using keras 2.2.4 currently
i am using keras 2.2.4 currently
i am using keras 2.2.4 currently

**Defining nvidia model**

```
def nvidia_model():
  model = Sequential()
  model.add(Conv2D(24, 5, 5, strides=(2, 2), input_shape=(66, 200, 3), activation='elu'))
  model.add(Conv2D(36, 5, 5, strides=(2, 2), activation='elu'))
  model.add(Conv2D(48, 5, 5, strides=(2, 2), activation='elu'))
  model.add(Conv2D(64, 3, 3, activation='elu'))
  
  model.add(Conv2D(64, 3, 3, activation='elu'))
#   model.add(Dropout(0.5))
  
  
  model.add(Flatten())
  
  model.add(Dense(100, activation = 'elu'))
#   model.add(Dropout(0.5))
  
  model.add(Dense(50, activation = 'elu'))
#   model.add(Dropout(0.5))
  
  model.add(Dense(10, activation = 'elu'))
#   model.add(Dropout(0.5))

  model.add(Dense(1))
  
  optimizer = Adam(lr=1e-3)
  model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=optimizer)
  return model
model = nvidia_model()
print(model.summary())
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223024/discussion-on-question-by-vivek-kumar-typeerror-keyword-argument-not-understo).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this method:

```
def nvidia_model():
  model = Sequential()
  model.add(Conv2D(24,(5,5), strides=(2, 2), input_shape=(66, 200, 3), activation='elu'))
  model.add(Conv2D(36, (5,5), strides=(2, 2), activation='elu'))
  model.add(Conv2D(48, (5,5), strides=(2, 2), activation='elu'))
  model.add(Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='elu'))
  
  model.add(Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='elu'))
#   model.add(Dropout(0.5))
  
  
  model.add(Flatten())
  
  model.add(Dense(100, activation = 'elu'))
#   model.add(Dropout(0.5))
  
  model.add(Dense(50, activation = 'elu'))
#   model.add(Dropout(0.5))
  
  model.add(Dense(10, activation = 'elu'))
#   model.add(Dropout(0.5))

  model.add(Dense(1))
  
  optimizer = Adam(lr=1e-3)
  model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=optimizer)
  return model
model = nvidia_model()
print(model.summary())
```

Comment: model.add(Conv2D(24, 5 strides=(2, 2), input_shape=(66, 200, 3), activation='elu'))
                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: please help.. please

Comment: yes i have edit with the right model.Reload the page.

Comment: please upvote my answer too if you try useful this aswer for other who have your problem =)

Answer (score 1):

It explicitly says that subsample is unknown.
Try replacing "subsample" with "strides", in recent versions of keras it is called that way.

Comment: TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'strides'

Comment: Can you paste your new Conv2D?